# How to implement the traccar API in android studio?

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate the traccar API with android but I can not integrate it.

If someone could explain how to integrate it, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traccar uses standard JSON-based REST API. You can use libraries like Retrofit to communicate with it. You can check official [Traccar Manager app source code](https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-manager-android/tree/native) for usage examples.